# How to filter a mongoDb collection based on a foreign key in MEAN stack app?

Tags: angular, mongodb, angular7, mean-stack

In my MEAN stack app, I have a `Venue-Detail` component, I am trying to display all upcoming events associated with this venue.

Below is an example of what the `venue` collection in my mongoDb looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb"),
    "venue_name" : "diceys",
    "venue_location" : "camden street",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I also have an `event` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d415feedb87bc4470c560be"),
    "event_name" : "test event",
    "event_venue" : "5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb",
    "event_artist" : "5d406855171c152868ba71c8",
    "event_price" : "10",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As you can see, `venue._id` is the same as `event.event_venue`.

I have the below code that gets all events:

```
getEvents(): void {
    this.eventService
      .getEvents()
        .subscribe((data: Event[]) => {
            this.events = data;
    });
}
```

I've stored the `venue_id` in a variable below, so I just need to filter events based on that

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.venue_id = params.get('id');
});
```

Event Service:

```
getEvents() {
    return this
      .http
        .get(`${this.uri}`);
}
```

But can someone please tell me how I can filter out the `events` object above based on the venue? I.e. only show events that are linked to this venue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the below code:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of myEvents">
    Event Name: {{event.event_name}}
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
getVenueId(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        this.venue_id = params.get('id');
    });
    this.getAllEvents();
}

getAllEvents(): void {
    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(events => {
        this.allEvents = events;         
        this.filterMyEvents(this.allEvents);
    });
}

filterMyEvents(allEvents): void {
    this.myEvents = allEvents.filter(event => event.event_venue === this.venue_id);    
}
```

First, I retrieve a list containing all the events, then use the `venue_id` to filter that list to display only events related to that venue

Answer (score 0):

Use mongoDB's `$lookup` stage from aggregation :

```
   db.venue.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: ObjectId("5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb") } }, {
    $project: {
        "_id": {
            "$toString": "$_id"
        },
        venue_name: 1,
        venue_location: 1
    }
}, {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 'event',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'event_venue',
        as: 'eventsList'
    }
}])
```

Or if you've too many fields in venue and it wouldn't be nice to list down everything in `$project` as above, Please use below query, also making _id to string as in event collection event_venue is stored as string :

```
db.venue.aggregate([{$match:{_id:ObjectId("5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb")}},{
    $addFields: {
      "_idString": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'event',
       localField: '_idString',
       foreignField: 'event_venue',
       as: 'eventsList'
     }
},{$project :{
   _idString:0 }}])
```

Or if you don't mind `_id` returned as string :

```
db.venue.aggregate([{$match:{_id:ObjectId("5d40590dd4ea332774e940cb")}},{
    $addFields: {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      },
      venue_name : '$venue_name'
    }
  },{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'event',
       localField: '_id',
       foreignField: 'event_venue',
       as: 'eventsList'
     }
}])
```

You don't need to use `ObjectId()` of _id when you're using mongoose as it internally takes it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but will this work in Typescript?

Comment: This is mongoDB query, try it on your DB and if it's working as your expectations then we're good, it should work in .ts , Same way as you're doing db.venue.find() so this db.venue.aggregate(). Give it a try and let me know if you're having any issues.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. I only showed the `db.venue.find()` to show the structure of my collections

Comment: @user9847788 : How are you making calls to mongoDB? Once your venue model is defined and connected to DB then try this from code.

Comment: I have an _API_ folder as my backend, it contains a Server.js file, a DB.js file, a routes folder & a models folder in my API project. The `getEvents()` method above retrieves all event collections from the mongodb. There's too much code in the backend to put up, just know that `getEvents()` returns all events. I just need to filter them somehow based on the venue

Comment: @user9847788 : Ok that way then, it's not related to mongoDB, more of client code needs to be changed to filter for necessary docs, Does getEvents gets all documents from events collections?  If yes, Do you really need all events ? If not just pass the venue _id to getEvents() and use my query to retrieve only the needed events based on venue id, that way it will be more efficient.